# Path planning using an occupancy grid with specific constrains

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, robotics

I have a binary occupancy grid representing an environment where zeros denote empty spaces and ones denote walls. I need to plan a path for a differential wheeled robot with a cylindrical shape. However, I have specific constraints that I am struggling to meet.

My objective is to generate a path that allows the robot to follow walls while maintaining a certain safe distance from the wall to avoid damaging it, additionally, I would like the robot to maintain a given maximum distance from the walls whenever possible. As an example in the distance trasform grid below I want a path that spans between ~15 and ~20, so when possible the path should go below the given maximum distance in order to cover certain areas of the map.

Could someone suggest an approach or algorithm that can help me achieve my desired path while considering these constraints? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Occupancy Grid:
[image: Occupancy Grid]

I have already attempted to generate a path by applying a distance transform to the grid and using it as a basis for planning. However, the resulting path is not perfect and exhibits some issues.

Distance Transform:
[image: Distance Transform]

Obtained Path:
[image: Obtained Path]

Desired path:
[image: Desired path]

Answer (score 0):

- Set R to the spacing you want between the robot and the wall.
- Construct a rectangular grid of cells with spacing between the cells of R
- Mark all cells the do not contain a wall and are less the 2 * R from a wall.
- Create a graph with a vertex located at each marked cell and an edge between every adjacent vertex.
- Run route planning code to generate a path that visits every vertex in graph.

The last step is the tricky one!  For that, may I suggest my application called "Obstacle" which produces this sort of result:

[image]

Obstacle documentation and code:  https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Obstacles